# logo drawing over Jquery tab

Tags: jquery, css, tabs

i have a header and below that i am drawing JQuery Tab navigator. i have padding in left side in tab and i want header image to come over tab navigator area.As of now, it is hiding behind the panel.Image should not be hidden. Which property in CSS will do this? 
Here is [Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Pctm4/49/)

I tried with `

```
.logo 
{
    float:left;
    height:50px;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right:1.5em;
    z-index: 5;
}`
```

, but it does not work.
Thanks for looking into this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z-index` only has meaning for positioned elements. Therefore you'll need to add `position: relative;`:

```
.logo 
{
    float:left;
    height:50px;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right:1.5em;
    z-index: 5;
    position: relative;
}
```

reference: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/z-index